# C# Sorted list without LINQ and SORT

Tags: c#, string, list, insert, sorting

My question is that is it possible to create a list that sorts the objects in it upon these object being placed in them?

After not getting anywhere, I made a new linked list. The only task is to make this list ordered by the string field of the objects it will containt while remaining foreachable.

I have the following code:

```
class LancoltLista<T> : IEnumerable
{
    class ListaElem
    {
        public T tartalom;
        public ListaElem kovetkezo;
    }
    ListaElem fej;
    public void ElejereBeszuras(T elem)
    {
        ListaElem uj = new ListaElem();
        uj.tartalom = elem;
        uj.kovetkezo = fej;
        fej = uj;
    }

    public void VegereBeszuras(T elem)
    {
        if (fej == null)
        {
            ElejereBeszuras(elem);
        }
        else
        {
            ListaElem e = fej;
            while (e.kovetkezo != null)
            {
                e = e.kovetkezo;
            }
            ListaElem uj = new ListaElem();
            uj.tartalom = elem;
            e.kovetkezo = uj;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ListaBejaro(fej);
    }

    class ListaBejaro : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        ListaElem elso, jelenlegi;

        public ListaBejaro(ListaElem elso)
        {
            this.elso = elso;
            jelenlegi = null;
        }


        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (jelenlegi == null)
            {
                jelenlegi = elso;
            }
            else
            {
                jelenlegi = jelenlegi.kovetkezo;
            }
            return jelenlegi != null;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            jelenlegi = null;
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return this.jelenlegi.tartalom; }
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return this.jelenlegi.tartalom; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            elso = null;
            jelenlegi = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I'm not able to compare p.kulcs and kulcs.

Comment: Yours seems to be a linked list, more than a C# `List<>` (that is a dynamic array)

Comment: Yes this is a linked list as I cannot use the build in one.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be a linked list?

Comment: So it is simple... You go through the list and you look for the first element greater than the element you want to insert. You insert your element before that element. You have to handle the special cases of insertion after the last, insertion of the first element (absolutely the first, so with an empty list), and of insertion before the first element (you already have an element in the list, you insert another that goes before the first element).

Comment: Or you can cheat, and use two special elements that are always present but that are skipped on enumeration. Like doorstops. In this way you don't have to handle any special case, because any element you insert will be between these two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real world applications you could use the built-in [`SortedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For your homework, you will have to check every item that you get in your add method against the entire list and insert it into the correct place: between the last element that it's grater than or equal to, and the first element that it's smaller then.
Of course, if the list is empty, or if there is no element greater than the one you add, then you simply append the element to the last available location.

Since this is homework, I'll leave you to write the code yourself.

Comment: I am stuck with how to compare those strings.

Comment: Strings? this is the easy part - you can simply do stringA.CompareTo(stringB). You need to worry about objects that doesn't implement the `IComparable` interface

Comment: [this is how](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/sortedlist.cs,650e966119d0cc88) `SortedList<T> works if you need inspiration

Comment: I have no idea how to make this list enumerable now

Comment: you mean you don't know how to implement IEnrumarable? Why don't you check how Microsoft did it in the link Franck provided? btw just out of curiosity, what language are you using for your variable names?

Comment: Hungarian language, and yes, I am fully out of touch and have no idea what the hell I am trying to do here, I have always just used LINQ,

Comment: I have spent 2 hours trying to make an ordered linked list that is foreachable and got nowhere

Comment: yeah, well, homework is a b#$%h.... [Perhaps this link can help.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I)

Comment: .net 2.0 is not that old,  try Pascal for ancient technologies :-)

Comment: I beg you to help me, please, I am getting new errors every time
I edited the code

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't even read your code... Also, I don't know what error do you get and on what code line. Beside that, You should have enough information in the answer and the comments. Use the links we provided. I promise you will learn this stuff a lot better by doing it yourself then by having some stranger writing the code for you.

Comment: After taking a nap, I got around it. I use casting and comparing in the insert method, it works fine now.

Comment: Great! Please accept this answer or post the complete solution and accept you own answer so that people will know the problem is solved